# catkin_make error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

***Hello I am trying to build a package 'gruvy_usarsim_inf' by using catkin workspace. I have set the dependencies also; but when I type in the terminal "catkin_make" following error comes.***

root@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws# catkin_make

Base path: /root/catkin_ws

Source space: /root/catkin_ws/src

Build space: /root/catkin_ws/build

Devel space: /root/catkin_ws/devel

Install space: /root/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/root/catkin_ws/build"

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /root/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /root/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.71
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - gruvy_usarsim_inf
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'gruvy_usarsim_inf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(gruvy_usarsim_inf)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package control_msgs.

Set control_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
for control_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
control_msgsConfig.cmake
control_msgs-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
gruvy_usarsim_inf/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package nav_msgs.

Set nav_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
nav_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
nav_msgsConfig.cmake
nav_msgs-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
gruvy_usarsim_inf/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package sensor_msgs.

Set sensor_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
for sensor_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
sensor_msgsConfig.cmake
sensor_msgs-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
gruvy_usarsim_inf/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package tf.

Set tf_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for tf.
The file will have one of the following names:

```
tfConfig.cmake
tf-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
gruvy_usarsim_inf/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78891/catkin_make-error/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to install that dependency depending on what version you have. If you have Indigo and below you can do it through apt-get. If you're running jade or higher then you have to build from source.

Here are some command to try :

sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y

---

Originally posted by [spottybadrabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/25136/spottybadrabbit/) with karma: 36 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MTDzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/35839/mtdzi/) on 2018-06-13**:
This worked for me (+1).

Just one correction: it's not a single command, it should be split into three:

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y
```